# Which hook should I use to display shipping methods?

Tags: woocommerce

I need to display my shipping methods. Which hook should I use to do this?

functions.php:

```
add_filter('which_hook_should_i_use', 'my_shipping_function');
function my_shipping_function() {
    //what code do I need to write?
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to display them?

Comment: @Ali_k, Shipping Flat Rate: 100$ (for example). $my_flat_rate_price instead of 100$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this way:

```
function ed_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {

foreach ( $rates as $rate ) {
    $first_product_id = array_values(  WC()->cart->get_cart()  );
    $product_id = $first_product_id[0]['product_id'];

    $rate_label = mb_strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $rate->label));
    $rate->cost = get_post_meta($product_id,'_my_shipping_method_'. $rate_label, true) ; // to form meta_key
  }
  return $rates ;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'my_package_rates', 10, 2);
```